# Find and append characters of a String by matching with a List in Python 2.7

Tags: string, python-2.7, list, character, match

There is a list contains with character sequences such below:

```
seq_list = ['C','CA','CAF','CMMVF','E','CMM','CMMF','CMMFF',...]
```

and a string can be defined as below:

```
a_str = 'CAFCMMVFCMMECMMFFCCAF'
```

The problem is to match the longest character sequence of `seq_list` in `a_str` from left to right iteratively, and then a character`('|')` should be appended if it's found.

*For example*,

> `a_str` begins with `'C'` but the actual character sequence is `'CAF'` because `'CAF'` has the longer sequence than `'C'`,
>   so that it should be achieved such below:

```
a_str = 'CAF|CMMVFCMMECMMFFCCAF' #actual sequence match
        'C|AFCMMVFCMMECMMFFCCAF' #false sequence match
```

Then, remaining `a_str_r` should be like this `a_str_r = 'CMMVFCMMECMMFFCCAF'` after a character `'|'` has been appended. So that the iterative process has to start over again by matching the longest sequence from the list until the end of the string, and the final result should be like this:

```
a_str = 'CAF|CMMVF|CMM|E|CMMFF|C|CAF|'
```

This was one of the attempts for this problem, and still couldn't get right!

```
a_str_r = []

for each in seq_list:
    for i in a_str:
        if each in i:
            a_str_r.append(i+'|')
return a_str_r
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to search for leftmost longest match. That is a standout for a regular expression search.

```
import re
seq_list = ['C','CA','CAF','CMMVF','E','CMM','CMMF','CMMFF']
# Sort to put longer match strings before shorter ones
sseq_list = sorted(seq_list, key=lambda a: len(a), reverse=True)
# Turn list into a regular expression string
sseq_re = '|'.join(sseq_list)
# Compile regular expression string
rx = rx = re.compile(sseq_re)
# Put pipe characters between the matches
print '|'.join(rx.findall('CAFCMMVFCMMECMMFFCCAF'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response :)